# LinkedList sum function deletes the entire list once finished?

Tags: java, linked-list

This is for practice purposes not a real world problem.

I am summing all the nodes of  `int` data type in a linked list this works fine.

I am also summing all the nodes with even numbers of `int` data type in a linked list this works fine.

But when I call one after the other in the test class the entire list is empty(Well set to null).

I think it is to do with this line `head = head.next;`

`data()` returns the data stored on that node

TEST Class

```
  linkedList.addTail(4);
  linkedList.addTail(7);
  linkedList.addTail(2);
  linkedList.addTail(7);

  linkedList.sum();

  //The list is empty here 
  linkedList.sumEven();
```

Linked List

```
public int sum(){
        int sum = 0;

        while (head != null) {  
            sum += head.data;  

            //Here 
            head = head.next;  
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
    }


public int sumEven(){
        //To keep track of the sum 
        int sum = 0;  

        while (head != null)  
        {  

            //If the data at head is even add 
            if (head.data() % 2 == 0)  
                sum += head.data;  

            //Or Here
            head = head.next;  
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;  
    }
```

Comment: Don't modify `head`. Copy it to a ***local** variable* and use that reference to walk the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `head` every time you assign it. You can either make a copy of it before summing or sum using a for like similar to the following.

```
for(Integer i: head) sum += i;
```

I have assumed that the elements in your LinkedList are of type int.